# Generate only one MSI @ a time from one solution, where as the solution has many project.

Tags: tfs, build

I need to build for Microservice project, where the project has only one solution and it generated three MSI for three project of microservice(eg:address,delivery,messaging) are three microservices, when the solution is build in tfs.

i want out of these all the microservice i need to generate MSI only for Delivery, not other MSI should generate and no other project should build with this one solution.

How can i do it with TFS build definition and TFS build template.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the project file that you want to build in Build Definition, not solution file.

[image]

Comment: But how can the wix project and other files will build if only we include the .csproj

Comment: You can add all the projects that you want to build in this item.

Comment: i tried this and added all the cs.proj files in items to build and selected the wix project.

Comment: i am building with Mixed platform and the Wix in on x86 and wix is ging error.

Comment: error:candle.exe: The parameter 'arch' is missing or has an invalid value Mixed Platforms.  Possible values are x86, x64, or ia64.

Comment: pls help with this

Answer (score 0):

The msi package is generated by the WiX project. According to your description, you should have three WiX projects in your project to create MSI packages for each project. You can create a new build configuration from "Configuration Manager" with the service project and WiX project you want to build checked only and then save and check in the changes. Now when you queue a build from TFS with the new created build configuration, only the MSI package you want will be created.
[image]

Comment: So then every checkin we should select the Wix project and then checkin is it ?

Comment: @rinoraju I'm sorry I'd get you. Can you explain your question more detail?

Comment: in the Build Definition i have mentioned the configuration to build as "Mixed Platform | Release". the project which i am building is "x86" Release and the dependent project are in "Any CPU". so when i build this projects during the build i am getting error:candle.exe: The parameter 'arch' is missing or has an invalid value Mixed Platforms. Possible values are x86, x64, or ia64

Comment: @rinoraju Does "Mixed Platform" exist in your configuration?